# Spring Boot Not Loading Test Specific Application Properties During Citrus TestNG Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testng, citrus-framework

I am trying to have Spring Boot autoload the `src/test/resources/application.properties` file instead of the `src/main/resources/application.properties` file when running my Citrus integration tests. The properties are usable during the tests, but they do not override the main properties that are used inside the main Spring Boot application.

Here is my configuration so far:

**src/main/java/EventPublisher.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EventPublisher {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EventPublisher.class, args);
  }
}
```

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
consumer.to=stream:out
```

**src/test/java/EndpointConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@SpringBootTest
public class EndpointConfig {
...
```

**src/test/java/CitrusTestsIT.java**

```java
@Test
@SpringBootTest
public class AutomatedIT extends TestNGCitrusTestRunner {
...
```

**src/test/resources/application.properties**

```
citrus.rest.server.port=7913
consumer.to=localhost:${citrus.rest.server.port}/consumer
```

**pom.xml spring snippet**

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I assume there's an annotation or file structure issue , but I have so far not been able to figure out what that issue is.

***Update***

I got the test properties to load from `src/main/resources` after renaming the file to `application-test.properties` and changing the `spring-boot` plugin in the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <profiles>test</profiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By setting the profile to `test` within the POM, now Spring Boot loads the test properties.

This doesn't seem like the correct way of doing this, and this also restricts the use of the `application-test.properties` file to the main Spring Boot application, and not to the testing package.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the two files exactly the same thing, `application.properties`. This means that only the single file with the highest precedence will be read; in this case, it's the one in your `src/test`. Instead, use Spring's profile feature to rename your override file to `src/test/resources/application-test.properties`, which will allow Boot to see both files and apply the overlay logic you want.

Comment: I added `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to `src/test/java/CitrusTestsIT.java` and renamed the properties file in `src/test/resources` to `application-test.properties`. The logs say the profile was set to test, but none of the test properties were used.

Comment: The `test` profile should normally be added automatically, I believe. Check your console logs, and it will tell you which profiles are being used (and which property sources).

Comment: If I don't include the annotation, I see this in the logs: `No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default`.

Comment: I managed to get the `application-test.properties` file to be loaded from the `src/main/resources` folder. See my update.